# gen [Generated Java File]

Tags: java, generated

My project cannot be export in 64 bit PC as there is unsolved problem in gen [Generated Java File] part. It can be run yesterday on 32 bit PC. Is there any relationship between PC version?

Comment: Well, it's morning here xD

Comment: i need 10 reputation to add picture of this post...please help me

Comment: Add a link, I'll make it a picture.

Comment: Also, give us more picture as to what kind of frameworks or libraries are you using and which IDE has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`gen` is auto-generated, you may clean the project, and rebuild it. In Eclipse, choose "Project" → "Clean...".